# How to create a <xhtml:link ... /> with DOMDocument

Tags: domdocument

The sitemap is created with DOMDocument and everything works fine. Now I want to create it multilingual. How can I create the xhtml:link  element in the following code?

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.ihremusterdomain.de/english/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.ihremusterdomain.de/deutsch/" />
  <lastmod>2014-04-15T16:13:34+02:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

The other elements like url, loc, lastmod and changefreq yet exist.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can do like:

```
var linkElement = document.CreateElement("xhtml:link", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

You need to provide full qualified name along with namespace uri.

Answer (score 0):

Because the node is in the XHTML namespace, you need to use [`createElementNS`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php) to add it:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->load('sitemap.xml');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('loc') as $loc) {
  $node = $doc->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'xhtml:link');
  $node->setAttribute('rel', 'alternate');
  $node->setAttribute('hreflang', 'de');
  $node->setAttribute('href', str_replace('english', 'deutsch', $loc->textContent));

  if ($loc->nextSibling) {
    $loc->parentNode->insertBefore($node, $loc->nextSibling);
  } else {
    $loc->parentNode->appendChild($node);
  }
}

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->save('output.xml');
```